How to pause a mongodbatlas cluster programmatically via python, either using an API or python package?
I want to pause a Mongodb-Atlas cluster automatically. How can I do that?
Through Atlas Cli, we have this command
atlas clusters pause  [options]
But I want to run this command via python.
Please tell me how.
Apparently, it's not allowed via Pymongo.
I tried
import os
os.system("atlas clusters pause Cluster0 --projectId 662b391615a47202d49f2fa0 --output json")


and
import requests
import json

# Atlas API configuration
base_url = "https://cloud.mongodb.com/api/atlas/v1.0"
project_id = "662b391615a47202d49f2fa0"
cluster_name = "Cluster0"

# Your Atlas API credentials
public_key = "YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY"
#private_key = "YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY"

# Endpoint for pausing a cluster
endpoint = f"{base_url}/groups/{project_id}/clusters/{cluster_name}"

# Request headers
headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Accept": "application/json"
}

# Request payload
payload = {
    "paused": True
}

# Send the PATCH request
response = requests.patch(
    endpoint,
    auth=(public_key),
    headers=headers,
    data=json.dumps(payload)
)

# Check the response
if response.status_code == 200:
    print(f"Cluster {cluster_name} paused successfully.")
else:
    print(f"Failed to pause cluster. Status code: {response.status_code}")
    print(response.text)

but both didn't work.

I believe if you change your payload to the following, it will work:
# Request payload
payload = {
    "paused": "true"
}

